# Fill the missing/incorrect values for the gender

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have this SQL Query:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (Gender VARCHAR(15))
INSERT INTO @table
VALUES 
    ('F'), 
    ('AAA'), 
    ('M'), 
    ('null'), 
    ('NULL')
```

How do I write a scalar function to clean this Gender column, inserting either F or M in place of "AAA" or in those nulls.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this, but what are the conditions with which you determine if it should be M or F?

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET gender = 
             CASE
                 WHEN -- your condition where you determine if it should be M -- 
                      THEN 'M'
                 ELSE 'F'
             END
WHERE LOWER(gender) NOT IN ('m', 'f')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create yourTable
(Gender bit not null)
```

bit only have `0` or `1`

```
select 
    case gender 
    when 1 then 'F'
    when 0 then 'M'
    end as gender
from yourTable
```

or use char(1) in your table

Comment: `bit` datatype saves only 0s and 1s (or NULLs). He might just want M and F, which is much clearer.

Comment: when datatype is 0, you select it show F, when datatype is 1, you select it show M. it is like my sql. when 1 then F, when 0 then M.and set your column(gender) not null.

Comment: or you could use char(1),then the column(gender) could insert one char.

Comment: Of course, but maybe he just wants simple code which he can understand and apply. I'm not saying yours is wrong, just complicated a bit (if he already has his table structure created and data in the table).